# Checking and setting default variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Let's say you have an object, TRACK, for tracking

```
TRACK = {};
TRACK.pageName = pageName || TRACK.buildPageName();
```

This would work fine if there was this somewhere before it:

```
var pageName = "Home";
```

Let's assume a way to fix this is:

```
TRACK.pageName = (typeof pageName != 'undefined' ? pageName : TRACK.buildPageName());
```

Is there a better practice for doing this with large javascript objects?

Comment: I think "TRACK.pageName = pageName || TRACK.buildPageName()" is quite acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are in a browser, you can do `window.pageName` to check the pageName value.

```
TRACK.pageName = window.pageName !== undefined ? pageName : TRACK.buildPageName();
```

But it's not really a "better" pratice. It's just a second way to do this. Using `typeof` is fine too.

Comment: Thanks - I was mostly looking for better practices on how to handle null variables before using shorthand syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your example:

```
TRACK.pageName = pageName || TRACK.buildPageName();
```

is correct, but if you want to campare with `undefined` here is a way to do that:

```
if (pageName !== undefined){...}
```

Comment: You can't do that. If `pageName` does not exist, you will get an error like `pageName is undefined`. You can't use a undeclared/unknown variable in javascript except in the `typeof` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could implement this if statement inside TRACK.buildPageName().
If pageName is global variable you can access it from inside TRACK.buildPageName()

```
{
...
    buildPageName: function() {
        this.pageName = (typeof pageName != 'undefined' ? pageName : TRACK.innerBuildPageName());
    }
}
```

Thanks to this, you can hide and implement this if statement only once.